# General questions about docker nodemcu-build

Tags: docker, nodemcu

Some general questions about the docker nodemcu-build process:

1. Is there a way to specify which modules are included in the build? (similar to the way the cloud build service works)
2. Is there a way to include a description that will appear when the resultant firmware is run?
3. Is SSL enabled?
4. The size of the bin file created by the docker nodemcu-build process (from dev branch source) is 405k.  A recent build using the cloud service resulted in a bin file of size 444k.  The cloud service build only included the following modules: cjson, file, gpio, http, net, node, tmr, uart, wifi, ssl.  Why is the docker build bin file, that contains all modules(?), smaller than the cloud build bin file that only contains 10 modules? (i am concerned that my local docker build version is missing something - even though the build process was error free).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You specify the modules to be built by uncommenting them in the [/app/include/user_modules.h](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/app/include/user_modules.h) file in the source tree. The default build from the source tree is relatively minimal - not an "all modules" build.
2. The banner at connection is the "Version" field. The nodemcu-build.com builds change this out for custom text. It is defined in [/app/include/user_version.h](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/app/include/user_version.h) as the `USER_VERSION` define. You'll need to embed "\n" newlines in the string to get separate lines.
3. Yes, the Net module can include [limited SSL support](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/net/) (TLS 1.1 only) (TLS 1.2 in dev per Marcel's comment below). You need to enable it in [/app/include/user_config.h](https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/blob/master/app/include/user_config.h#L67) by defining `CLIENT_SSL_ENABLE`.
4. The default module and config setup in `user_modules.h` / `user_config.h` is different than the defaults on nodemcu-build.com, so the builds are not likely to be the same out of the box.

Comment: Thanks for answering all those questions for "my" project :) Just a small note that the `dev` branch now contains a different SSL implementation that supports TLS 1.2 as well, see https://www.facebook.com/NodeMCU/posts/645938968907767

Comment: Thanks for the great service/project @MarcelStör .

Comment: Hello, is it still `USER_VERSION` in the current version of NodeMCU? Or is it `NODE_VERSION` now?